# How to add custom image as Logo with Bootstrap class navbar-brand in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, django-bootstrap3

Many thanks for your support.I am a newbee to Django and Bootstrap.

When I downloaded a bootstrap template it came with a logo.png.If I point to this image with below code all works

```html
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
    <!-- Logo Image -->
    <img src="{% static '/img/logo.png' %}" width="100" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2">
    <!-- Logo Text -->
    <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Brand Name</span>
</a>
```

However if I place a custom image(test.png) within the same folder? of logo.png and point to that.The site does not show the logo.

1. I tried resizing test.png to same as logo.png
2. I tried using other images on my system
3. Only the default logo and images that comes with templates works.

What am i missing please? 
Please help me.

Comment: Is this in your local development environment or on production? Can you show your folder structure where we can see the location of /img/logo.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a production server then:

You need to use `python manage.py collectstatic` to get your new image into the directory where your static files are being served. That directory you specify in the `STATIC_ROOT` setting in your project's `settings.py`.

After executing `collectstatic` you should be able to spin up the server and the image in your link should be ***test.png***.

This is all Django, and nothing to do with Bootstrap.

Edit: As [dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten) points out several ways of dealing with static files are explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/). Note the difference between the development server and a production server.

Comment: This assumes the OP is deploying to production and the problem is there, which isn't clear. On the local development environment, STATIC_ROOT and collectstatic are irrelevant.

Comment: A better reading is [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Thanks so much.I had a separate static folder defined for development and somehow forgotten it.All images were put in the production Static folder and when I copied them to the development static folder everything started working.

Many Thanks